# "AngularCli" does not exist in the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices" namespace

Tags: angular6, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli but get error like this ("AngularCli" does not exist in the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices" namespace). I added packege with command dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices --version 2.0.1,but I still have problem with SpaServices

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli`, it exists under `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions` package instead of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices`.

Try to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions`.

Answer (score -1):

I had Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions installed, but had to update it.

Was using ASP.NETCore 3.1